# Control Vertical Axis Numbering

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column chart created within SSRS, and on that column chart I also have two line charts placed. I'd like the Vertical axis numbering to be determined by only the column portion of the Chart, but so far I cannot figure out how to set this up.

An image is attached to highlight the problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting which axis the values corresponded to corrected this issue. The Lines needed to be all set to Secondary and the columns Primary.